# Not Showing div because parameter(value) passed is behaving like a string not div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor-2

There is a problem in JavaScript it's not showing the desired *div* on click as parameter passed is value(Id of AWB) but it's behaving like a string *value*.

**View.cshtml**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>@item.AWBNO
    </td>
    <td>@item.AIRLINENAME
    </td>
    <td>@item.CARGODATE
    </td>
    @foreach (var itema in entity)
    {


        if (itema.AWBNo == @item.AWBNO)
        {
            Filled = true;
            DCNo = itema.DCNumber;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Filled = false;
        }
    }
    <td>
        @if (!Filled)
        {
        @Html.ActionLink(" ", "AddOn", "Section82", new { instanceId = item.AWBId }, new { @class = "AddOn" })                
        }
        @if (Filled)
        {
            <div id = @item.AWBId  style="display: none;" >
                MyTextOnClick</div>
            <button onclick = "Show(value)" value = @item.AWBId>
                ClickMe</button>    
        }
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

**JS:**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function Show(value) 
{
    alert(value);
    $("#value").show(); // here is the major problem it's not getting id although in alert it showing the right id.
}
</script>
```

the major problem it's not getting id of div to show although in alert its showing the right AWBId Please Help.

Comment: Show what the HTML the *browser* sees is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to concatenate the value to the `#` while using it.

```
function Show(value) 
{
    alert(value);
    $("#"+value).show();
}
```

**EDIT:** Adding code for your comment

HTML:

```
<button class="some-class-name" value = @item.AWBId>
    ClickMe
</button>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.some-class-name').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('value'); 
    $("#"+id).show();
});
```

Since you're using JQuery, you can do something similar to the edit.

Comment: Shall we able to get the id of individual without passing it as parameter? like I did in function Show(value) is there any way?

Comment: @ShahAbdullah, edited to match what I understood from your question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to substitute `value` into the string:

```
function Show(value) 
{
    alert(value);
    $("#" + value).show();
    //   ^^^^^^^^ The + appends the value of `value` to the string
}
```

So for instance, if `value` contains "foo", you'll end up with `"#foo"`, which looks for the element with the `id` `"foo"`.

Be sure to follow the [CSS rules for the `id` values](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) on your elements, because that's a CSS selector. (Although if it thinks it can, jQuery will use `document.getElementById` which means it sometimes allows some invalid CSS `id` selectors where, say, `querySelector` or a stylesheet wouldn't.)

Comment: Crowder Thumbs for the reasoning Iam trying but is there a way to debug the values in view and through break point in MVC view? like I want to investigate the flow. (additional Question)

Comment: Crowder Shall we able to get the id of individual without passing it as parameter? like I did in function Show(value)

Comment: @ShahAbdullah: There would be two parts to that: Server-side as the HTML is being created, and client-side as the JavaScript code is running. Server-side you can use the debugger built into VS.Net (I don't know about the Razor part of it). Client-side, there's a debugger built into your browser -- press F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I or look for "dev tools" on the menu.

Comment: @ShahAbdullah: If you change your `onclick`, you can use `this.value` within `Show`: `<button onclick = "Show.call(this)" value = @item.AWBId>` You might also consider adding the event object: `<button onclick = "Show.call(this, event)" value = @item.AWBId>`

Comment: Crowder For Client side debugging I downloaded FireBug it's awesome and working well Thank you very much brother !